# Divide elements of a sorted array into least number of groups such that difference between the elements of the new array is less than or equal to 1

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

**How to divide elements in an array into a minimum number of arrays such that the difference between the values of elements of each of the formed arrays does not differ by more than 1?**

Let's say that we have an array: `[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17]`.
The array elements are sorted.

I want to divide the elements of the array into a minimum number of array(s) such that each of the elements in the resulting arrays do not differ by more than 1.

In this case, the groupings would be: `[4], [6], [8, 9, 10, 11], [14], [16, 17]`. So there would be a total of **5** groups.

How can I write a program for the same? Or you can suggest algorithms as well.

I tried the naive approach:
Obtain the difference between consecutive elements of the array and if the difference is less than (or equal to) 1, I add those elements to a new vector. However this method is very **unoptimized** and straight up fails to  show any results for a large number of inputs.

Actual code implementation:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int num = 0, buff = 0, min_groups = 1;    // min_groups should start from 1 to take into account the grouping of the starting array element(s)
    cout << "Enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
    cin >> num;

    vector<int> ungrouped;
    cout << "Please enter the elements of the array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cin >> buff;
        ungrouped.push_back(buff);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < ungrouped.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((ungrouped[i] - ungrouped[i - 1]) > 1)
        {
            min_groups++;
        }
    }

    cout << "The elements of entered vector can be split into " << min_groups << " groups." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "However this method is very unoptimized and straight up fails to compile for a large number of inputs.". That doesn't make sense, any size should compile. Please show your attempt in code, this is not free code-writing service.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)?

Comment: Also, your naive approach should be O(n) which is optimal. Just iterate over the differences, adding elements to an array, and when you encounter >2, create a new array and start adding appending to it.

Comment: @Quimby Thanks for pointing that out. It does compile, but fails to show any results even after waiting a long time. I have edited the content of my post to reflect the correct event.

Comment: What makes you say that it is unoptimized ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because most of the algorithms involving such a procedure falls into the general category of "unoptimised". I was optimistic that there might be a better way involving STL data structures... I had no idea. I searched on the web and I was getting the same results like my implementation. So I came to SO for help.

Comment: This argument is more than questionable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The downvotes on this post are reflecting it.

Comment: *most of the algorithms involving such a procedure falls into the general category of "unoptimised"* Says who?

Comment: *and straight up fails to show any results* Your implementation is buggy.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: this has nothing to do with a partition à la Quicksort. Did you even read the question ?

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses. But I don't really understand what's **too broad** about this question. I targeted a very specific problem and tried my best to explain it.

Comment: @GourabIX: neither do I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by Faruk's answer, if the values are constrained to be distinct integers, there is a possibly sublinear method.

Indeed, if the difference between two values equals the difference between their indexes, they are guaranteed to belong to the same group and there is no need to look at the intermediate values.

You have to organize a recursive traversal of the array, in preorder. Before subdividing a subarray, you compare the difference of indexes of the first and last element to the difference of values, and only subdivide in case of a mismatch. As you work in preorder, this will allow you to emit pieces of the groups in consecutive order, as well as detect to the gaps. Some care has to be taken to merge the pieces of the groups.

The worst case will remain linear, because the recursive traversal can degenerate to a linear traversal (but not worse than that). The best case can be better. In particular, if the array holds a single group, it will be found in time O(1). If I am right, for every group of length between 2^n and 2^(n+1), you will spare at least 2^(n-1) tests. (In fact, it should be possible to estimate an output-sensitive complexity, equal to the array length minus a fraction of the lengths of all groups, or similar.)

---

Alternatively, you can work in a non-recursive way, by means of exponential search: from the beginning of a group, you start with a unit step and double the step every time, until you detect a gap (difference in values too large); then you restart with a unit step. Here again, for large groups you will skip a significant number of elements. Anyway, the best case can only be O(Log(N)).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest encoding subsets into an offset array defined as follows:

- Elements for set #i are defined for indices j such that offset[i] <= j < offset[i+1]
- The number of subsets is offset.size() - 1

This only requires one memory allocation.

Here is a complete implementation:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::size_t> split(const std::vector<int>& to_split, const int max_dist = 1)
{
  const std::size_t to_split_size = to_split.size();
  std::vector<std::size_t> offset(to_split_size + 1);
  offset[0] = 0;
  size_t offset_idx = 1;
  for (std::size_t i = 1; i < to_split_size; i++)
  {
    const int dist = to_split[i] - to_split[i - 1];
    assert(dist >= 0);  // we assumed sorted input
    if (dist > max_dist)
    {
      offset[offset_idx] = i;
      ++offset_idx;
    }
  }
  offset[offset_idx] = to_split_size;
  offset.resize(offset_idx + 1);
  return offset;
}

void print_partition(const std::vector<int>& to_split, const std::vector<std::size_t>& offset)
{
  const std::size_t offset_size = offset.size();
  std::cout << "\nwe found " << offset_size-1 << " sets";
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i + 1 < offset_size; i++)
  {
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (std::size_t j = offset[i]; j < offset[i + 1]; j++)
    {
      std::cout << to_split[j] << " ";
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> to_split{4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17};
  std::vector<std::size_t> offset = split(to_split);
  print_partition(to_split, offset);
}
```

which prints:

```
we found 5 sets
4 
6 
8 9 10 11 
14 
16 17
```

Comment: @YvesDaoust this is a classical technique, use for instance to store spare arrays... nothing really hard, see explanation at the end of the post

Comment: @YvesDaoust What don't you understand?

Comment: You added the bottom after my comment. I do not consider that throwing code with no explanation is a valid answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust is it fixed now?

Comment: Yes, I prefer this, it gave me the info I was looking for. (Though the next step is to discard the code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array. Whenever the difference between 2 consecutive element is greater than 1, add 1 to your answer variable.

`

```
int getPartitionNumber(int arr[]) {
    //let n be the size of the array;
    int result = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        if(arr[i]-arr[i-1] > 1) result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

And because it is always nice to see more ideas and select the one that suites you best, here the straight forward 6 line solution. Yes, it is also O(n). But I am not sure, if the overhead for other methods makes it faster.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using Data = std::vector<int>;
using Partition = std::vector<Data>;

Data testData{ 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17 };

int main(void)
{
    // This is the resulting vector of vectors with the partitions
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> partition{};  
    // Iterating over source values
    for (Data::iterator i = testData.begin(); i != testData.end(); ++i) {
        // Check,if we need to add a new partition
        // Either, at the beginning or if diff > 1
        // No underflow, becuase of boolean shortcut evaluation
        if ((i == testData.begin()) || ((*i) - (*(i-1)) > 1)) {
            // Create a new partition
            partition.emplace_back(Data());
        }
        // And, store the value in the current partition
        partition.back().push_back(*i);
    }

    // Debug output:  Copy all data to std::cout
    std::for_each(partition.begin(), partition.end(), [](const Data& d) {std::copy(d.begin(), d.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe this could be a solution . . .

Comment: `std::prev(partition.end())->push_back(*i);` -- Should be simply `partition.back().push_back(*i)`;`  -- Much more understandable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Absolutely correct. I will of course update. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

How do you say your approach is not optimized? If your is correct, then according to your approach, it takes `O(n)` time complexity.

But you can use binary-search here which can optimize in average case. But in **worst** case this binary search can take more than `O(n)` time complexity.

Here's a tips,
As the array sorted so you will pick such a position whose difference is at most **1**.

Binary search can do this in simple way.

```
int arr[] = [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17];

int st = 0, ed = n-1; // n = size of the array.
int partitions = 0;
while(st <= ed) {
    int low = st, high = n-1;
    int pos = low;
    while(low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high)/2;
        if((arr[mid] - arr[st]) <= 1) {
            pos = mid;
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    partitions++;
    st = pos + 1;
}
cout<< partitions <<endl;
```

In average case, it is better than `O(n)`. But in worst case (where the answer would be equal to **n**) it takes `O(nlog(n))` time.